# Blackberry 10.3 native SDK installation not proceeding - stuck at 28%

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-jde, momentics

I have been trying to install blackberry 10 native SDK for the past two days, the progress bar has just stayed on a point and I don't know what to do. When I cancel, and then go to the update center to do the installation it moves on and also get stuck at a particular file (fetching bbndk:win32.libraries.10.3.0.698.zip).

Comment: I'm having the same problem when trying to install it on my other PC... Ridiculous, I can't figure it out either. I'll let you know if I do!